# MySQL Error 2013

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I am facing connection failure to MySQL problem when I run my program for more than couple of days.MySQL Error Code is 2013 while connecting to Database. MySQL server and client programs are both on same machine. I am using FC5 as my OS and MySQL version is 5.0.18. Can anybody throw some light on this?

I am getting mysql error 2013 while calling `mysql_real_connect()`...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try using localhost, instead of your own IP. 
I don't know why, but this immediately fixed the problem for me.

I would be very grateful if someone could clarify 
why this worked, all of a sudden.

Comment: mysql uses a local socket when connecting to 'localhost' - it's an idiosyncrasy of mysql that 'localhost' isn't looked up to 127.0.0.1 but rather signifies a socket based connection.  It takes TCP/IP out of the equation and provides a more straightforward interface instead.

Answer (score 4):

1. Sounds like a firewall issue. Have you tried disabling the firewall temporarily?
2. Another possible solution involves edition the startup script as mentioned [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,45914,120196#msg-120196) and commenting out the following line:

   SKIP=skip-networking
3. A third possible solution is mentioned [here](http://www.tutorials.de/forum/relationale-datenbanksysteme/194826-mysql-error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-mysql-server-during-query.html#post1011024). The user tried to access an InnoDB database and InnoDB support was accidentially deactivated for the MySQL server.
4. **(new)** I found [this official MySQL article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) which has lots of approaches to solve the problem. Did you modify the wait_timeout system variable?

Comment: 1. Client and server both are on same machine. So firewall may not be a issue
2. skip-networking is already disabled. Anyways, its not an issue as client and server do not communicate thru TCP/IP if both are on same machine

Comment: error is coming while calling msyql_real_connect(), so underlying database storage engine is irrelevant here.

Comment: Of course the firewall can be the source, even on the same machine. What OS are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer you might not expect.  I had encountered the same problem. MySQL Error 2013.  Here are the symptoms:

1. PHPMyAdmin fired off 2013 and error 95.
2. I could shell into the MySQL monitor, but it took an inordinately long time to start.  I could view tables and everything worked once the command line utility started
3. The server took a LONG time to stop and restart.
4. No errors in the MySQL error log.

I work with a good sysadmin who checked netstat -tn, which yielded the answer:

```
tcp        0      0 [my.srv.ip]:3306     184.73.87.215:59271     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 [my.srv.ip]:38138    184.73.87.215:113       SYN_SENT
```

The IP resolves to Amazon Web Services.  Some prick was leeching onto my 3306, even though everything but port 80 is allow-only.  It's time to review my firewall rules.

There were no new tables, and mtop didn't show any activity, but I found a ton of these in the auth log:

```
Apr 19 15:14:52 magic2 mysqld[18953]: refused connect from ec2-184-73-87-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Apr 19 15:18:02 magic2 mysqld[18953]: refused connect from ec2-184-73-87-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

After blocking the offending IP in iptables, the problem suddenly went away.  Sneaky Bastards.  The moral of this story is: What looks like bug, might be a hacker.

bz

Comment: sounds like bad Security Groups to me.  Everything but port 80 is "allow-only"?  Is that a type-o, or a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1):

Check your my.cnf.  Set your bind-address to the server's IP address.  Solved the issue for me.  NO ONE seemed to know the answer to that one!

Answer (score 1):

My fix was - change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

It could be a network error that caused the TCP/IP connection to drop, or the wait_timeout was exceeded on the server; the latter can actually be useful in keeping the # of open connections down, but the app will then need to handle errorcode 2013 correctly!!

Comment: client and server both are on same machine, so they do not communicate through TCP/IP.

Comment: @VVS: if the host is 'localhost', mysql will use a local unix socket connection. If the host is '127.0.0.1', it will use a TCP/IP connection.