# MySQL OPTIMIZE all tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL has an [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) command which can be used to reclaim unused space in a MySQL install.  Is there a way (built-in command or common stored procedure) to run this optimization for every table in the database and/or server install, or is this something you'd have to script up yourself?

Comment: Be careful in that this will not necessarily reclaim space.  If you are using InnoDB with a single file (probably the most common setup these days) rather than separate files per table, you will still use the same amount of disk space at the end.  In fact I have seen it actually use significantly more disk space when all was said and done.  With large tables, the table may be locked for a very long time as well.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` was useful for MyISAM.  Now that that Engine is going away, the need for `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is going away, especially the need to periodically optimize all tables.

Comment: +1 for good info rick -- but given standard real world database practices, I wouldn't be surprised if old MyISAM tables remain around for another decade

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You can use [`mysqlcheck`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) to do this at the command line.

One database:

```
mysqlcheck -o <db_schema_name>
```

All databases:

```
mysqlcheck -o --all-databases
```

Comment: would you recommend this command to be scheduled to run at least once a month?

Comment: Hi @Gaia. Not necessarily. Optimizing all tables on a given schedule is not beneficial for everyone. Take a look at this post and read the comments for much more in depth thought on this topic than I can provide in limited space here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2010/02/07/how-often-should-you-use-optimize-table/

Comment: more like "probably not" unless you're avoiding large tables and are cognizant of which tables are InnoDB vs MyISAM

Comment: simple use : `mysqlcheck -u [username] -p[password] -o [database name]`

Comment: Please be advised that tables are *locked* while OPTIMIZE is being performed, which can take a substantial time if the tables hold lots of data. So, during the time a table is being OPTIMIZE'd, no new records can be inserted or deleted. Generally, OPTIMIZE'ing all tables of a production system cannot be considered as a trivial operation.

Comment: @No-Chip it depends on which client you are using. For example if you are using *Mysql Workbench* , follow this answer : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57261

Comment: Thank you @Eray but i was thinking more in the direction of pure SQL statements.

Comment: @No-Chip you can optimize tables in the MySQL client using the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html. For example, optimize one table like this: `OPTIMIZE TABLE <your_schema>.<your_table>;`, optimize all tables in a given schema like this: `select concat('OPTIMIZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') into outfile '/tmp/optimize_all_tables.sql' from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'pabeta' and table_type = 'base table'; source /tmp/optimize_all_tables.sql;`

Comment: you can also use `mysqloptimize <db_schema_name>` directly

Comment: Also worth noting that sometimes there are a better alternatives to `OPTIMIZE`. For large tables where changes can be detected easily it can be better to do: 1. Create copy of the table without indexes, 2. Copy current data (`INSERT ... SELECT`), 3. Add indexes, 4. lock table in transaction, 5. Copy changes, 6. `RENAME` new and old tables. This keeps tables locked for the minimum amount of time, but requires suitable data (can `SELECT` changes easily, e.g- using a `TIMESTAMP` column). I wouldn't run anything like that regularly though, only when necessary.

Answer (score 38):

I made this 'simple' script:

```
set @tables_like = null;
set @optimize = null;
set @show_tables = concat("show tables where", ifnull(concat(" `Tables_in_", database(), "` like '", @tables_like, "' and"), ''), " (@optimize:=concat_ws(',',@optimize,`Tables_in_", database() ,"`))");

Prepare `bd` from @show_tables;
EXECUTE `bd`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `bd`;

set @optimize := concat('optimize table ', @optimize);
PREPARE `sql` FROM @optimize;
EXECUTE `sql`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `sql`;

set @show_tables = null, @optimize = null, @tables_like = null;
```

To run it, simply paste it in any SQL IDE connected to your database.

Notice: this code **WON'T work** on phpmyadmin.

## How it works

It runs a `show tables` statement and stores it in a prepared statement. Then it runs a `optimize table` in the selected set.

You can control which tables to optimize by setting a different value in the var `@tables_like` (e.g.: `set @tables_like = '%test%';`).

Comment: My shared hosting environment doesn't have 'mysqlchk' available so I could run this directly from a 'mysql' terminal session.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I use this code to optimize 50 databases and spend the minimum amount of time as possible. If you think I can improve the code in any way, go ahead and give me your suggestions. I will be happy to improve this precious piece of code.

Comment: Prepare `bd` from @b Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel this is MySQL, your answer uses TSQL syntax and won't work with MySQL.

Comment: @Phrancis I used this on MySQL Workbench and it worked always perfectly.

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti Thank you for confirming it. I'm glat that, even after 2 years, this code is useful to, at least, 10 persons. That is a huge victory for me! Once again, thank you!

Comment: Can you adjust your code to also work for every table of every SCHEMA ?

Comment: I believe that that's out of the scope of the question, and a massive pain.

Comment: After using this script, my CPU load is 200/200% on MySql 8 server and my site is not working RN. Output of the script was OK. HELP ??

Comment: @Bojmaliev That's WAY outside the scope of this answer. But seems that something went belly up on that server. Either the server is in a deadlock or being slammed with requests it can't answer to or your database has so many tables in such an unoptimized state with so much data that the server is just gridding it. I honestly don't know. Those are the only things I can see. (Note: this code does basically the same that the PHP script does.)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yea, I know. I really dont know what happened but it happened the second i run the script. I guess some transaction failed and it tried to rollback it, but the database was huge.  I solved it by reinstalling mysql server.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel your script works perfectly and is massively useful. Thank you eight years later! One question: is there any benefit to running this script over something like `mysqlcheck -uuser -p --optimize --databases myDatabase`

Comment: @DianaEftaiha If you don't have SSH access, you can run this script. That's really the only advantage. If you have any way to run commands, that would be the preferred way. If you need to run this from PHP, you might find that Scherbius.com's answer is better, or try to run the command from PHP. There are no specific benefits from running the script over running the command, as far as I know.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to analyze, repair and optimize all tables in all databases in your MySQL server, you can do this in one go from the command line. You will need root to do that though.

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases
```

Once you run that, you will be prompted to enter your MySQL root password. After that, it will start and you will see results as it's happening.

Example output:

```
yourdbname1.yourdbtable1       OK
yourdbname2.yourdbtable2       Table is already up to date
yourdbname3.yourdbtable3
note     : Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
status   : OK

etc..
etc...

Repairing tables
yourdbname10.yourdbtable10
warning  : Number of rows changed from 121378 to 81562
status   : OK
```

If you don't know the root password and are using WHM, you can change it from within WHM by going to: 
**Home > SQL Services > MySQL Root Password**

Answer (score 25):

Following example php script can help you to optimize all tables in your database

```
<?php

dbConnect();

$alltables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");

while ($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($alltables))
{
   foreach ($table as $db => $tablename)
   {
       mysql_query("OPTIMIZE TABLE '".$tablename."'")
       or die(mysql_error());

   }
}

?>
```

Comment: On a database with 200 tables you are going to run 200 separate queries optimising 1 table at a time. You should implode the table names into one string and hence only one optimize table query is required.

Comment: I wonder if the separate query approach is sometimes better. MySQL says the tables are locked while OPTIMIZE TABLE is running.  Then it would seem wiser to optimize each one at a time to let the server acquire locks for the minimum time. Obviously that's for a server that keeps been accessed. If not, then I think a single query iss the best approach.

Comment: What would the script look like if you imploded and made into 1 query? Thanks.

Comment: @Dean The separate query approach is often better to give breathing room for a live application. In fact, I usually add a delay (just 750ms or so) for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 21):

Do all the necessary procedures for fixing all tables in all the databases with a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqlcheck --all-databases
mysqlcheck --all-databases -o
mysqlcheck --all-databases --auto-repair
mysqlcheck --all-databases --analyze
```

Answer (score 13):

From phpMyAdmin and other sources/editors you can use:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 99999999;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('OPTIMIZE TABLE `', table_name, '`;') SEPARATOR '') AS O
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_name!='dual'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your databasename>'
```

Then you can copy & paste the result to a new query or execute it from your own source.
If you don't see the whole statement in phpMyAdmin:
[image: way to see whole statement in phpmyadmin]

Comment: that was a nice answer, but my phpmyadmin do not show the whole command, just the first ones then ... sad for me, lol.

Answer (score 11):

for all databases:

```
mysqlcheck -Aos -uuser -p
```

For one Database optimization:

```
mysqlcheck -os -uroot -p dbtest3
```

Comment: At least for me, under Linux, the command `mysqlcheck -Aos` does not require user+password.

Answer (score 5):

From command line:

```
mysqlcheck -o <db_name> -u<username> -p
```

then type password

Answer (score 4):

You can optimize/check and repair all the tables of database, using mysql client.

First, you should get all the tables list, separated with ',':

```
mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] -Bse 'show tables' [DB_NAME]|xargs|perl -pe 's/ /,/g'
```

Now, when you have all the tables list for optimization:

```
mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] -Bse 'optimize tables [tables list]' [DB_NAME]
```

Answer (score 4):

my 1 cent, added `and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` so we can skip the '`VIEW`' type.

```
for table in `mysql -sss -e "select concat(table_schema,'.',table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_schema not in ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' order by data_free desc;"`
do
mysql -e "OPTIMIZE TABLE $table;"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

The `MySQL Administrator` (part of the MySQL GUI Tools) can do that for you on a database level.

Just select your schema and press the `Maintenance` button in the bottom right corner.

Since the GUI Tools have reached End-of-life status they are hard to find on the mysql page. Found them via Google: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

I don't know if the new MySQL Workbench can do that, too.

And you can use the `mysqlcheck` command line tool which should be able to do that, too.

Answer (score 2):

A starter bash script to list and run a tool against the DBs...

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a dbs
unset opt

for each in $(echo "show databases;" | mysql -u root) ;do

        dbs+=($each)

done



echo " The system found [ ${#dbs[@]} ] databases." ;sleep 2
echo
echo "press 1 to run a check"
echo "press 2 to run an optimization"
echo "press 3 to run a repair"
echo "press 4 to run check,repair, and optimization"
echo "press q to quit"
read input

case $input in
        1) opt="-c"
        ;;
        2) opt="-o"
        ;;
        3) opt="-r"
        ;;
        4) opt="--auto-repair -c -o"
        ;;
        *) echo "Quitting Application .."; exit 7
        ;;
esac

[[ -z $opt ]] && exit 7;

echo " running option:  mysqlcheck $opt in 5 seconds  on all Dbs... "; sleep 5

for ((i=0; i<${#dbs[@]}; i++)) ;do
        echo "${dbs[$i]} : "
        mysqlcheck $opt ${dbs[$i]}  -u root
    done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing database directly then you can write following query:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table1,table2,table3,table4......;
```

Answer (score 0):

my 2cents: start with table with highest fragmentation

```
for table in `mysql -sss -e "select concat(table_schema,".",table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_schema not in ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') order by data_free desc;"
do
mysql -e "OPTIMIZE TABLE $table;"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This bash script will accept the root password as option and optimize it one by one, with status output:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  echo
  echo "ERROR: root password Parameter missing."
  exit
fi
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=$1
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
TBLLIST=""
COMMA=""
SQL="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE"
SQL="${SQL} table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
for DBTB in `mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"`
do
    echo OPTIMIZE TABLE "${DBTB};"
    SQL="OPTIMIZE TABLE ${DBTB};"
    mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for the highly-accepted answer to fail in several cases.  `mysqlcheck -o --all-databases` is excellent, but you may find yourself in need of the `--skip-database` argument, in case you run into:

- Databases-enabled for mysql to exist (`information_schema`, `performance_schema`, `sys`, etc.).
- Databases-enabled for mysql to do replication (`defaultdb`).
- Databases-enabled for your cloud virtual host (`mysql` on Digital Ocean, apparently).

In that case, give this a whirl:

```
mysqlcheck -o --all-databases --skip-database=information_schema;performance_schema;sys;defaultdb;mysql
```

Answer (score -2):

If local moderators allow this, I would like to promote a PHP library I wrote quite some time ago - https://github.com/Simbiat/optimize-tables
The point of the library is to allow "smart" execution of the OPTIMIZE, ANALYZE, CHECK and REPAIR commands depending on table's parameters and statistics. I've been running it in CRON for https://simbiat.ru for over 2 years now and it has been smooth sailing (aside from some adjustments and minor fixes, of course).

Why would you want to use something like this? Well, the README provides some more details, but in short, it can help with running relevant operations only when you can actually benefit from them. At the least, it can save your resources.