# Performance issues with mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I migrated my mysql database to docker and I restored a dump file. My mysql server was instaled directly on Linux, and I had not issues. On docker container my queries is 30x slower. Someone had a similar problem? I am running docker on Ubuntu 16 and I am using the following docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ~/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
       - .:/var/www/html/app/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: Can you dump your docker info, also which filesystem do you use and with which flags are they mounted?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/247 also there is some worthfull information there

Comment: [Something that worked for me was running mysqlcheck to fix the tables.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944159/2867894)

Answer (score 8):

don't know if it can still help you. Faced the same issue hence I tried to figure it out. Apparentley the volume from your host filesystem to the container slows it down dramatically. Try to use the following setup with your volume:

```
~/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
```

The only draw back is that it might take some time until the data written inside /var/lib/mysql will be written to your local filesystem.

Comment: Worked for me running Docker on Windows 10 (moby VM)

Comment: switched to docker-sync now, its mindblowing fast on mac os

Answer (score -2):

I did not encounter such a problem on my desktop, but mysql container was running very slowly in a way that I could not understand on my laptop computer. [This solution](https://phpforus.com/how-to-make-mysql-run-fast-with-ext4-on-ubuntu/) solved my problem.