# Can't run mysql console via ssh after restarting service

Tags: mysql, ssh

I use Ubuntu 12.04 x64, currently with Mysql 5.5.28 (plus Galera, but I don't think it's related). 
I made some changes in my.cnf, but changes was related to InnoDB settings (a lot more memory for the buffer pool, flush, thread concurrency settings etc.).

After that when I hit `service mysql restart` I cannot enter mysql console - I get following error message:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', 
  system error: 104
```

Sometimes next try results in entering console, sometimes not and I have to restart my SSH connection. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

EDIT:
I noticed that most of the time after the `system error: 104` following error occurs:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

After few times it usually starts. Unfortunately now it didn't and in syslog there is:

```
Error in my_thread_global_end(): 2 threads didn't exit
```

Restarting SSH connection / MySQL server is not working. I can try reboot server but I'd try to resolve this without that step. Its testing environment so I want to find better solution than restart whole server ;)

Comment: check your bind-address in my.cnf - it shoudlnt be localhost/127... I believe. try 0.0.0.0 (auto detect free IP of system) or the actual one ;-)

Comment: I commented bind-address - if I didn't and use Galera multi-master it would result in total destruction ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Please try the answers in this page:- [Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)
- Also try [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-system-err-741347/#edit3613768).