# mysql error in connection to the server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2
```

error while I'm going to connect my db.

If I'm using localhost everything is working fine. But when I'm using my live IP address like the one below, I'm getting the error:

```
mysql_connect("202.131.xxx.106:xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: try only 202.131.xxx.106 put into hostname ?

Comment: Try this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)

Comment: i already search in google. i didnt find solution

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use just localhost?

Try without port number.

or

Please check your server configuration and which port you are using.

Comment: OP is trying to connect to the production server, read the question again :) also how to try without port number if the server is configured to run on a different port.

Comment: Are you accessing database from other server?

Comment: i need to DB access from server. how to remove port number?

Comment: no. i am not accessing from other server. i am accessing my own server

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things:

1. Make sure your Live IP is open to public requests
2. Port is working fine. Usually MySQL use 3306
3. Another way to check port is working or not is to use it with `localhost`
4. The user you are using has object(db) access
5. Try using root user credentials (but only for testing strictly)
6. If its connecting with root credentials then create two separate users `my_user@localhost` and `my_user@%` and grand object access

Comment: if i put localhost its working fine. but i have to access from my server. Please help me.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to access MySQL on one server from another server. In that case you skipped the Point 1. You need to enable remote access on MySQL server so it can be accessed by other server. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844804/1032299 on how to enable remote access.