# Linking MySQL server on Sql Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, sql-server-2008

In our application I have to transfer data from between a MySql Server deployed on Linux machine and a SQL Server deployed on a Windows machine, its both the ways.
We plan to do it by creating MySql as a linked server on SQL Server. I have created a DSN pointing to the Linux Server and it shows "Connection Successfull" when I "test" it.

I get the following error when I try to add the same MySql server as a linked server

```
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLDNS". 
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLDNS" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

The DSN I am using is a System DSN. I have tried with a User DSN too.
I can connect to the mysql instance using a MySQL Workbench. I can telnet into it too.

> Our MySQL is installed on a 64 bit linux machine and the SQL Server is a 32 bit windows machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste is not the scenario we are using it in. I have seen the response.Its not a firewall issue and the MySQL config has been verified for loopback

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too - 64 bit ODBC version 8 driver from MySQL, using 64 bit Windows and 64 bit SQL Server. For me it was the Connection Timeout property on the linked server in SQL Server