# How to connect to mysql server with sqlyog?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog, mysql-5.7

I try like this : https://postimg.org/image/fmq76lsf1/

I had input mysql host address, username and password

There is exist error like this :

```
Error No.2013
Lost connection to mysql server at 'readig initial communication packet', system error:34
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5755819/4932070

Comment: Check this one too http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Comment: Thank you very much