# Basic MySQL Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

I just created a mysql docker container using

```
docker run -p 3310:3310 --restart always --env MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% --name=ipca-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

I am able to connect to my database using `docker exec -ti ipca-mysql bash` and `mysql -u root -p`

But when I tried to connect to my database at `localhost:3310` using mysql workbench I get:

> lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication
>   packet' system error 0

Any idea what is this issue?

Comment: The port number is normally 3306. If you run `netstat -pltn` in the container is it exposing at port 3306?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker mysql on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637013/docker-mysql-on-different-port)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL container start using this command it's worked.

```
docker run -p 3310:3306 --restart always --env MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% --name=ipca-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this docker command:

```
docker run --name mysql-tacs -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d -p 3310:3306 mysql
```

In the link below there is a video which shows step by step the creation of mysql server with docker until the connection in its server using MySQL Workbench.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZwvhMvUJiw