# Docker MySQL "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost" outside of terminal

Tags: mysql, docker, credentials

I know that this is a fairly common error, but the curious thing is that in this case the credentials work when I'm logged in to Docker and working with mysql in the terminal. But when I try to use a client like DBeaver or MySQL Workbench, or even making an API call via Python, I get the error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost".

I thought it might be because I have another local MySQL database using port 3600, so I changed it to 3700 but the problem persists. I've made sure that the image is running in the Docker application, and besides, as mentioned, it works using the terminal. This is on MacOS Ventura. If there's any other information I can provide that would help, please let me know. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: It's always one of the following reasons: 1) wrong password, 2) wrong instance But with your description is rather hard to say which one it is here

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that the password is correct, because it's the same one that I use to log in to the terminal. I don't know what to do about the wrong instance, though - I'm fairly new to docker.

Comment: This was resolved by the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637013/docker-mysql-on-different-port