# Google analytics code fires twice on transaction page of my website.

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I had pasted GTM code once in my website. But the analytics code fires twice which send duplicate data in google analytic.[image]

In this image you can see a GA id i.e. UA-73604757-3 fires twice.
I just want know why this is happening.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python actually...

Comment: You might get answer from the earlier post. click [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)