# Setting up ODBC data source to connect to MySQL database on LAN

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have a MySQL/wampserver set up on a local computer on my home network. I was able to successfully set up an ODBC data source on that computer.

I now want to be able to access the data from other computers in my home. I've got to the point of being able to access the database using phpmyadmin from other computers after fiddling with windows firewall and various other settings. However I need to set up an ODBC data source on these other computers to connect to the data using Matlab. This is where I got stuck. I got the following error when testing the ODBC data connection:

Connection Failed [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0:

I have tried ports 80 and 3306. Tried both the ANSI and Unicode MySQL drivers (v5.3).

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste)

Comment: Per the answer on the link that @Nico provided, I would try turning off firewalls on both (all) systems to see if the problem persists. That is usually the first thing I try when troubleshooting a network-related issue. Update us after you try that.

Comment: Yes, turning off the firewall worked. It turns out I needed to add an extra port for the firewall inbound rule. Thank you.