# Problems connecting Laravel to a remote MySQL database: "Lost connection to MySQL server at handshake" and "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: mysql, laravel

I got this problem where I have developed a Laravel application which uses or connects to a external database.

I have copied all Laravel files in a CentOS server that needs to connect to a MySQL database that is located in another (Ubuntu) server.

Locally, I didn't have any trouble with Laravel Homestead.

But now the Laravel app throws the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

And if I try to connect to the external database from the CentOS terminal,

```
$ mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -P 3306 -u user4laravel -p
```

I get this other error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake:
>   reading inital communication packet', system error: 11

**Notes**: I connect to that server via SSH Tunnel with SSH-KEY and passphrase. Do I have to create a tunnel connection?

How do I make it persistent? Is this practical? Or  ...
Does anybody know how to solve this or a workaround?

Comment: I'd guess you have a firewall that isn't allowing connections on port 3306 to get through. Perhaps a software firewall running on the Ubuntu server, or perhaps other network routing issues.

Comment: [gone away possible causes/solutions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was because of `hosts.allow` file. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12062266/1883256)