Why can I connect to my docker container locally when I build it but not on my server?
I'm trying to run a docker container with MySQL, and I can build and run it on my local machine where I map 3306:3306 and can connect to it successfully in MySQL Workbench.
Here's my docker container:
FROM mysql:8.0

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=defaultdb

COPY create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

Then, I run it with:
docker run -d -v db-data:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 mysql-db
When I pull the image (I've uploaded it to dockerhub). On my server (which is running through Cloudflare's reverse proxy) I am just mapping port 8443:3306. When I try to connect from Workbench with example.com port 8443 root/password I get:
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet' system error: 0

I've tried:

running a GRANT permission on root, nothing changed.
changing the port to 3306:3306 on the server (which just said I couldnt connect to it at all)


How do your grants look? How about bind_address in my.cnf? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste.

Something on port 8443 I might expect to be HTTP-over-TLS; MySQL's wire protocol is neither.  Is something in your hosting setup sending a TLS handshake or expecting to get an HTTP request before it sends anything back?
