# mysql client on wlan

Tags: mysql, wifi, ubuntu

- I have mysql server on computer A (ip 192.999.1.1)
- Computer B is connected via wlan (Computer name: Vostro; ip 192.999.1.2)
- Both machines are running Kubuntu 14.04
- I want B to access mysql on A

Here is what I have done so far:-

1. Comment out bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. mysql> create user Vostro@192.999.1.2 identified by 'xxxxx';
3. Grant permission. mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO Vostro@'192.999.1.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxx';
4. Restart computer A

When trying to access 'A' from 'B':-

```
~$ mysql -u Vostro -pxxxxx -h192.999.1.1
```

I get:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Any ideas?

Have since found this posting which resulted in a working mysql client

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1...s-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You had some trouble formatting your question, so I fixed it for you. The MarkDown notation is used for layout which you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You might wanna check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578147/mysql-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communic

Answer (score 0):

The parts of an IP address can only be 0 - 255. So `192.999...` isn't a valid IP address. Private addresses should also (in your case) start with `192.168.`. Just try `192.168.x.y` (with `x` and `y` smaller than 255 ;)), like `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.2`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the ip addresses were fictitious

Comment: OK, I see... Then I'm afraid I can't see the problem. Possibly, Dorvallas suggestion to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578147/mysql-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communic may help you?