# Error during Django "Running migrations": django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

My Django project is connect to the remote MySQL database.

After I created all the model classes in Django, I tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Everything is fine. Then I entered

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then an error occurred during "Running migrations:", "Applying event.0002_auto_20150904_2141..."

Error code:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Does anyone know what might cause this error? I followed the exact procedures in the official Django tutorial.

Comment: Is your MySQL service up and running?

Comment: yeah definitely it is

Answer (score -1):

Please do this :
1- Install new fresh of mySQL server first.
2- Create new db 
3- Config in django settings like this :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'db_pass',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {"init_command": "SET storage_engine=MyISAM"},
}
```

4- Re-run syncdb
5- Re-run migrate
I hope this work