# How to reproduce mysql error 2013

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I'am using MySQL version 5.5.14-log and we upgraded recently. Now I'am getting 2013 error in MySQL 5.5.14-log version frequently and I'am not able to reproduce the issue manually, from my application (compiled with MySQL version 5.0.41) only it is reproducing.

Anybody help me to how to reproduce this error or resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011911/mysql-error-2013

Answer (score 0):

> got one answer on net, may this will help you.

[error-2013-hy000-0130 resolved](http://jerrywalsh.org/2009/solving-mysql-error-2013-hy000-0130.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the bind-address=localhost and restart MySQL server? Seems like this issue is related to yours: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,355740,355742#msg-355742

Also this-

> If MySQL port is wrong result is MySQL client error 2013 "Lost
>   connection ...". Note that this error also occurs if port forwarding
>   is disabled in SSH configuration (the configuration parameter
>   'AllowTcpForwarding' is set to 'no' in the 'sshd_config' file). It
>   (here) simply tells that there is no connection from SSH to MySQL for
>   some reason. But the mySQL client API 'thinks' there was one
>   connection and that is why is says 'Lost connection ...' and not
>   'Can’t connect...'. There was one successful connection - but not to
>   the MySQL server - to the SSH daemon only! But the MySQL client API is
>   not designed to 'see' the difference!

Refer [this](http://webyog.com/faq/22_113_en.html).