# MySQL Error 2013 after a failed attempt to import

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I was importing one table in a MySQL Server when the power went down. After this event I tried to query the table I was importing, but got the error 2013, only when I'm querying this table (the others work just fine).

I have physical access to the server, tried to execute any query from there (tried to SELECT, and even DROP TABLE) but still got the same error.

Does anybody know a solution where I can re-build only the table (without building the whole schema from scratch?)

Comment: Are you able to `mysqldump` this table ?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the table itself is there and the problem occurred when importing data into that table? Also try and do a search for 'Mysql 2013 error'. There might be someone on Stackoverflow or the Net who has had this problem too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011911/mysql-error-2013 this looks similar.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake: Yes, the table is there, and the problem occurred while i was importing the data... Your link isn't exactly the solution, because my DB is accessible through LAN only, but i'll keep searching the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer rather than having lots of comments underneath. I must state in advance that I've not used MySQL but I have used SQL server a lot so I'm hoping that something I say may help.

You say the table is still there. Was it created as part of the operation you were doing or had it been there for a while?

What happens if someone else or a different account tries to access this table?

Is there anything on this page that is relevant to your problem?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Could you please reproduce `2013 errno` once again and put here the results from mysqld.log?